# What are some potential applications of trilinear mappings?

Tags: diffie-hellman, group-theory

In "[Applications of Multilinear Forms to Cryptography](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/mlinear.pdf)" Boneh and Silverberg give "*one-round n-way Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol*" as a potential application of n-multilinear mappings.

If we focus on trilinear mappings in particular, what are some other applications?

Comment: We may be able to construct indistinguishability obfuscation from trilinear maps. https://ia.cr/2017/250

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE! It seems like somebody downvoted your question without stating why. I suppose it is because we prefer questions that can be answered, rather than open-ended questions. Cfr. for example the [help center](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, maybe I should reformulate. I don't think the question is as open ended as I made it sound. There is only a narrow range of plausible answers with respect to modern crypto.